# Why does MinGW automatically include <windef.h>

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I am trying to typedef DWORD in a platform agnostic manner, and I am running into the following compiler error:

```
...\mingw.org\mingw_gcc_4.5.0\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../
../../include/windef.h:229:23: error: 
'DWORD' has a previous declaration as 'typedef long unsigned int DWORD'
```

I'd like to be able to depend on my implementation of DWORD and not on the underlying compiler knowing what it is (using typedefs, not macros).

Why does mingw (gcc 4.5.0) automatically include "windef.h" when an application is compiled?

How does one prevent this inclusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My MinGW doesn't seem to automatically pull in `windef.h`. I suspect that your program is including some other header that's indirectly pulling it in. Can you post a short program that displays the problem?

Note that I see you're using whether or not `_WINDEF_H` is defined to determine if these things have already been typedef'ed.  That might work when MinGW is being used, but the actual Windows SDK defines `_WINDEF_` when `windef.h` is included - at least one specific version. I imagine this is fairly stable, but it's certainly possible that this has changed at some point.

It might be better to key on something like the macro `MAKEWORD` to detect whether `windef.h` has already been included - `MAKEWORD` is documented as being a macro defined in `windef.h`, so it should be stable across SDK versions, whether from Microsoft or not.

Answer (score 4):

Solved it,

It was being included by windows.h, included by a boost header file.

My header file which defines these typedefs simply looks for the presence of "_WINDEF_H" - and has a rule that it must be the last included header file (to give sufficient time for the windows header files to become included, thereby negating the need for my typedef).

Comment: Can you please provide info about **which boost header file**? This is most undesirable behavior of Boost. Bringing in a header with thousands of macro symbols that can collide willy-nilly with anything.